# Oscillator in Multisim

Tags: ac, analog, oscillator, simulation, multisim

newbie here.

As I read through webpages, i got to know that Oscillators are capable of changing DC to AC. I made a phase shift circuit in Multisim, but I got no idea what should I do next.

I was thinking using DC source as input and it will produce AC output, like some sinusoidal graphs. But if use AC Sweep, DC definitely will be open.

Any idea?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: An oscillator doesn't need an external AC source as an input.  Also, you *do need* to have a DC power source for your opamp.

Comment: So I will need to take out the AC source, and connect two DC source to power the OP-Amp right? I think I tried that, simulate by producing transient, but I got a fine straight line... Perhaps there's something wrong within the period setting..mind advise? thanks!!

Comment: Different simulators are picky about oscillators. You may also need to place an initial condition on one or more of the capacitors.  Update your post with your updated schematic.